# Login error message in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP code and here I want to display an error message in login.php if the user entered incorrect userid or password.below I have written two-page code. login.php page submits the username and password to the check.php page. if username and password are correct then it redirects to the xyz.php else to the login page.

**login.php** //login page

```
<form name="login" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="checkpage.php" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value="sandeep" onfocus="this.value=''" class="login-inp" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Password</th>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" class="login-inp" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-size" id="login-check" /><label for="login-check">Remember me</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td><input type="submit" class="submit-login"  /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><th></th><td>w want to display error message here..</td></tr>

</table></form>
```

**checkpage.php** //connection page

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //connecting to db
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    $q="select *from xyz where username='$username' AND password='$pwd'";
    $qry=mysql_query($q);
    if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        echo "<script>window.open('xyz.php','_self')</script>"; 
        }
        else{

            header("location:login.php");

            }
?>
```

the above code work fine but i want to display the error message how could i display the error message. please guide me.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the message to session in your check.php script and then unset immediately after getting it for display (AKA "read once"):

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Your message';
```

and then (in login.php, where you want the message to be displayed):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['message']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

Comment: Semantic! Sessions for flash messages. +1.
Also if you could inform him that once user puts correct password and logs in, session should clear 'message'.

Comment: The message is cleared right after displaying it. And it is set only when the login data was incorrect. So there's no need to do anything else. I believe that's how joomla is displaying the messages to the users as well so no new inventions has been done here :)

Answer (score 1):

Give a space between * and from in query.

```
$q="select * from xyz where username='$username' AND password='$pwd'";
```

1. For error message you can set a flag like `error= 1`

   header("location:login.php?error=1");
   and in login.php you can check this flag and display a message like

   ```
     <?php   If(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 1){ ?>
           <h3>Invalid username or password</h3>    
     <?php } ?>
   ```
2. You can set a session of error and display it in login.php and unset it after displaying.

   but donot forget to use session_start in both pages
   session_start();  //on top of page

   before header code add `$_SESSION['error'] = "you message here"`

in login.php

```
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['error'];
           }

          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    echo 'invalid username or password';
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {       
        $result = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $_SESSION['id_admin'] =     $result['id_admin'];
        $_SESSION['email'] =        $result['email'];
        $_SESSION['name'] =         $result['name'];
        $_SESSION['surname'] =      $result['surname'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] =         $result['pass'];


        header('Location: http://localhost/admin/dashboard.php');
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        echo  '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">Close X</a>
                <p><strong>Alerta!</strong></p>
                Email or password wrong! Please try again!.
            </div>';
    }

    $conn->close(); 
}

?>
```

Comment: put the <div> integrated error message wherever you pleased. It should work everywhere. pretty simple.

Comment: Maybe you can explain in your answer why and how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use Echo and include it at last thing on your page !!

```
<?php
//put it in the end of your php code
else {
    echo 'your message ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that how you can display error messages in your code.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['Username'])){
//session_start();
 $username = $_POST['Username'];
 $password =  $_POST['Password'];
//$r = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from  user where u_nm='".$username."' and password='".$password."'"));
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user where Username='".$username."' and Password='".$password."'");
$cnt = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
//echo $username;
//echo $password;
//echo $cnt;
if($cnt >= 1)
{
    
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
    header("Location:lessons.php");
}
else
{
    $msg = "<center><h4>Username or Password are not correct, try again.</center></h4>";
    header("Location:login.php?msg=$msg");
}
}
?>
```